# how linux select() system call monitor two files(file descriptors) and how to use timer argument

Tags: c, linux

I need to use `select` system call where I have to open two files (file descriptors) and do read operation on those files which are ready, I need to use some timeout after every 5ms and read from those files 
Here is my sample code:

```
int main()
{

    fd_set readfds,writefds;
    ssize_t nbytes,bytes_read;
    char buf[20];
    int fd_1,fd_2,retval;
    struct timeval tv;

    fd_1 = open("test1.txt", O_RDWR);
    if(fd_1 < 0) {
        printf("Cannot open file...\n");
        return 0;
    }

    fd_2 = open("test2.txt", O_RDWR);
    if(fd_2 < 0) {
        printf("Cannot open file_2...\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /* Wait up to five seconds. */
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    for(;;)
    {
        retval = select(FD_SETSIZE, &readfds, &writefds, NULL, &tv);
        printf("select");
        perror("select");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        //}
        for(int i=0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++)
        {
            FD_ZERO(&readfds);
            if (FD_ISSET(i, &readfds))
            {
                // read call happens here //
                nbytes = sizeof(buf);
                bytes_read = read(i, buf, nbytes);
                printf("%ld", bytes_read);
            }
            else
            {
                perror("read");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please, take an example with your sample codes.

Answer (score -1):

You need to initialize the file descriptors sets before calling `select()`. With your current code `select` ends up with `EBADF`.

Something like this should do it:

```
FD_ZERO (&writefds);

for(;;)
{
    FD_ZERO (&readfds);
    FD_SET(fd_1, &readfds);
    FD_SET(fd_2, &readfds);

    retval = select(FD_SETSIZE, &readfds, &writefds, NULL, &tv);
    if (retval < 0) {
        perror("select");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<FD_SETSIZE; i++)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(i, &readfds))
        {
            // read call happens here //
            printf("reading from file: %d\n", i);

            nbytes = sizeof(buf);
            bytes_read = read(i, buf, nbytes);
            printf("read %ld bytes\n", bytes_read);
        }
    }
}
```

And also you may want to check that `for(;;)` loop and only exit on error. Once your `select` behaves properly you can proceed with debugging inside your second `for` loop. You don't seem to use `writefds` here, so you may also just set it to `NULL` in `select`.

One more note: since you only have two files in the read set you could simply check `FD_ISSET(fd_1)` / `FD_ISSET(fd_2)` instead of iterating over all `FD_SETSIZE` entries.

Comment: i tried that way but i am not able to pass those file descriptors to select() system call here is where i got stuck

Comment: @rupsum_1998 I don't quite follow. What do you mean you're not able to pass those to select? What exactly is happening?

Comment: for example if there are 2 file descriptors, fd_1 is for a textfile,fd_2 for another textfile ,so the select system call should find which process is ready and  read operation is performed on that file(which is ready) .this is where i am not able to do.

Comment: @rupsum1998 And it does that. But you first need to add those two file descriptors in your `readfds` set as in my code sample above. After that you check the return value of `select` and, if successful go into your second loop and check which fds are ready to read from. But also don't wipe your `readfds` with FD_ZERO just before checking it ...

Comment: I tried the way you said(added fd_1 and fd_2 to readfds) and still there is no difference.please code the way you said and post your sample code if possible ,it would be helpful for my understandability.